# my contacts have dissapeared and i can't recover them with google backup

Tags: data-recovery

i bought a new Galaxy Core Prime about 2 weeks ago. After some time, some of my contacts dissapeared. I didn't delete them, neither switched any settings with contacts. Still i had 102 contact in my sim card and now i have only 48 and i didn't delete any of them. I tried Android Data Recovery, Google Backup but none of them worked.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you access your contacts at contacts.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

my advice is you should use "GT RECOVERY " APP in your android .but its need ROOT so first root your device  with KINGO ROOT. this is very easy.